# post request rewrite from curl to python requests

Tags: python, curl, post, http-post, python-requests

Why my post request via os.system('''curl ... ''') works correctly,
and the 'requests' analogue does not?

```
import requests

 .....

headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post('https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/' + uid + '/unfollow/', headers=headers, data={'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language': 'uk,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'cookie': 'mid=WFgEmgAEAAFwxSdDXrfo8AAFCuHb; datr=hapZWMkpCVayEtqUE9QZ1L_R;sessionid=IGSC13c5de61354c258b1d0a65658184b39292f3b37a6502121f2adc55f7f8477621%3ACjRnOP6jWX4XtHYSlGsnReUQfbE3Knqc%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A'+myid+'%2C%22_token%22%3A%22'+myid+'%3Afj3xkSGeTR3houFF08iwxKCWHEWOt6bi%3Adb47725d645f676bb23b2df6de97e39f435ab84078e36fcce4b86979036aa792%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%22'+publicIp+'%22%3A31148%2C%22time%22%3A1483005349%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1483005349.437956%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%7D; ig_pr=1; ig_vw=1367; csrftoken=3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f; ds_user_id='+myid,
    'x-csrftoken': '3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f', 'x-instagram-ajax': '1', 'accept': '*/*', 'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/'+username+'/following/', 'authority': 'www.instagram.com', 'content-length': '0', 'dnt': '1'})
print(r.status_code, r.reason) # 200 OK, but not unfollow
```

=============================================

```
import os

 .....

ulink = '''curl 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/''' + uid + '''/unfollow/' -X POST -H 'origin: https://www.instagram.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: uk,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mobile Safari/537.36' -H 'cookie: mid=WFgEmgAEAAFwxSdDXrfo8AAFCuHb; datr=hapZWMkpCVayEtqUE9QZ1L_R; sessionid=IGSC13c5de61354c258b1d0a65658184b39292f3b37a6502121f2adc55f7f8477621%3ACjRnOP6jWX4XtHYSlGsnReUQfbE3Knqc%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A'''+myid+'''%2C%22_token%22%3A%22'''+myid+'''%3Afj3xkSGeTR3houFF08iwxKCWHEWOt6bi%3Adb47725d645f676bb23b2df6de97e39f435ab84078e36fcce4b86979036aa792%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%22'''+publicIp+'''%22%3A31148%2C%22time%22%3A1483005349%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1483005349.437956%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%7D; ig_pr=1; ig_vw=1367; csrftoken=3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f; ds_user_id='''+myid+''' ' -H 'x-csrftoken: 3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f' -H 'x-instagram-ajax: 1' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://www.instagram.com/'''+username+'''/following/' -H 'authority: www.instagram.com' -H 'content-length: 0' -H 'dnt: 1' --compressed'''

unfollowAndShowStatus = os.system(ulink)
print(unfollowAndShowStatus) # {"status": "ok"}0,  unfollow correctly.
```

======================================
@j-a-k:

print(r.text) # blank screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head><meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
Instagram
</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    custom: {
      families: ['proxima-nova:n3,n4,n6,n7'],
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/scripts/webfont.js/c0456c81549b.js" async></script>

<style type="text/css">
  /* @license
   * MyFonts Webfont Build ID 2164953, 2012-03-23T23:06:30-0400
   *
   * The fonts listed in this notice are subject to the End User License
   * Agreement(s) entered into by the website owner. All other parties are
   * explicitly restricted from using the Licensed Webfonts(s).
   *
   * You may obtain a valid license at the URLs below.
   *
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Light by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/light/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Regular by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/regular/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Semibold by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/semibold/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Bold Italic by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/bold-it/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Bold by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/bold/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   * Webfont: Proxima Nova Italic by Mark Simonson
   * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/regular-it/
   * Licensed pageviews: unlimited
   *
   *
   * License: http://www.myfonts.com/viewlicense?type=web&buildid=2164953
   * Webfonts copyright: Copyright (c) Mark Simonson, 2005. All rights reserved.
   *
   * (c) 2012 Bitstream Inc
   */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot/115b1f7f9c04.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot/115b1f7f9c04.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.woff/618250d25a4d.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf/646346e03084.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.svg/e55a9d6051e8.svg#ProximaNovaBold') format("svg");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal; }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-boldit-webfont.eot/1cbb869da891.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-boldit-webfont.eot/1cbb869da891.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-boldit-webfont.woff/b1cf049474c9.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-boldit-webfont.ttf/3adb020ceae3.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-boldit-webfont.svg/29948a2d3c58.svg#ProximaNovaBoldItalic') format("svg");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic; }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-reg-webfont.eot/12af77715cee.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-reg-webfont.eot/12af77715cee.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-reg-webfont.woff/a9a9773b8e29.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-reg-webfont.ttf/99e19808976a.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-reg-webfont.svg/c33d2fd56309.svg#ProximaNovaRegular') format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-regit-webfont.eot/1bbbd1312b0d.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-regit-webfont.eot/1bbbd1312b0d.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-regit-webfont.woff/9e306befca91.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-regit-webfont.ttf/4a8663684135.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-regit-webfont.svg/876278d4b189.svg#ProximaNovaRegularItalic') format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic; }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-sbold-webfont.eot/5016edf79e1d.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-sbold-webfont.eot/5016edf79e1d.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-sbold-webfont.woff/615c1b06d8fa.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-sbold-webfont.ttf/2973bd483f7a.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-sbold-webfont.svg/868597833e49.svg#ProximaNovaSemibold') format("svg");
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal; }
</style>

  <style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-light-webfont.eot/63c84728610f.eot');
    src: url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-light-webfont.eot/63c84728610f.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-light-webfont.woff/66bbe029f180.woff') format("woff"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf/eb408516399b.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url(' //instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/webfonts/proximanova-light-webfont.svg/858f6a9b7ef3.svg#ProximaNovaLight') format("svg");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal; }
</style>



        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var docElement = document.documentElement;
            var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
            var className = docElement.className;
            docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
        })();
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window._timings = {"domLoading": Date.now()}</script>

                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/932e4d9af891.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png/004705c9353f.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png/82467bc9bcce.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="167x167" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-167x167-precomposed.png/515cb4eeeeee.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180-precomposed.png/94fd767f257b.png">
                <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/favicon-192.png/b407fa101800.png">

            <link rel="mask-icon" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/favicon.svg/9d8680ab8a3c.svg" color="#262626"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/images/ico/favicon.ico/dfa85bb1fd63.ico">





    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=el" hreflang="el" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ms" hreflang="ms" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=bg" hreflang="bg" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=zh-cn" hreflang="zh-cn" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=vi" hreflang="vi" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=pt" hreflang="pt" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=tl" hreflang="tl" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=tr" hreflang="tr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ja" hreflang="ja" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ne" hreflang="ne" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=nb" hreflang="nb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=fr" hreflang="fr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=kn" hreflang="kn" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=sr" hreflang="sr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=mr" hreflang="mr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=si" hreflang="si" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=nl" hreflang="nl" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=da" hreflang="da" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=cs" hreflang="cs" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ur" hreflang="ur" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=zh-hk" hreflang="zh-hk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=hr" hreflang="hr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=bn" hreflang="bn" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=te" hreflang="te" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ta" hreflang="ta" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ko" hreflang="ko" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=sv" hreflang="sv" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=fr-ca" hreflang="fr-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=af" hreflang="af" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=es" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=hu" hreflang="hu" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=it" hreflang="it" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=sk" hreflang="sk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=id" hreflang="id" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ru" hreflang="ru" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=fi" hreflang="fi" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=th" hreflang="th" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=gu" hreflang="gu" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ro" hreflang="ro" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=pt-br" hreflang="pt-br" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=pl" hreflang="pl" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=zh-tw" hreflang="zh-tw" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=hi" hreflang="hi" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=pa" hreflang="pa" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=ml" hreflang="ml" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=uk" hreflang="uk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/web/friendships/3533829984/unfollow/&amp;hl=en" hreflang="en" />

</head>
    <body class="">

    <span id="react-root"></span>




            <script src=//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/scripts/polyfills/es5-shim.min.js/6514c5e08593.js></script>
<script src=//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/scripts/polyfills/es5-sham.min.js/fc3c22cf2d67.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"entry_data": {"LoginAndSignupPage": [{}]}, "display_properties_server_guess": {"pixel_ratio": 1.5, "viewport_width": 360}, "environment_switcher_visible_server_guess": true, "qe": {"br": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "us_li": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "freq": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "gql": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "us": {"p": {"use_continue_text": "true"}, "g": "continue_vs_signup_text_test_03"}, "feed": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "ebd": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "activity_stories": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "su_universe": {"p": {"can_phone": "true"}, "g": "control"}, "discovery": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "profile": {"p": {}, "g": ""}}, "show_app_install": true, "gatekeepers": {}, "platform": "web", "language_code": "en", "config": {"viewer": null, "csrf_token": "c09xND4tYnQUZ1Vk7SwtRGxFHsTIgY4C"}, "static_root": "//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1", "hostname": "www.instagram.com", "country_code": "UA", "activity_counts": null};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/bundles/en_US_Commons.js/e0324e108f49.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/bundles/en_US_LoginAndSignupPage.js/398e77eae9cf.js"></script>

<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1425767024389221');

fbq('track', 'PageView');


</script>
<noscript>


</noscript>


            <script type="text/javascript">window._timings.domInteractive = Date.now()</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confused your `cookies` and your `headers` with your `data`.  I think you should write this as:

```
cookies = {
    'mid': 'WFgEmgAEAAFwxSdDXrfo8AAFCuHb',
    'datr': 'hapZWMkpCVayEtqUE9QZ1L_R',
    'sessionid': 'IGSC13c5de61354c258b1d0a65658184b39292f3b37a6502121f2adc55f7f8477621%3ACjRnOP6jWX4XtHYSlGsnReUQfbE3Knqc%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A'+myid+'%2C%22_token%22%3A%22'+myid+'%3Afj3xkSGeTR3houFF08iwxKCWHEWOt6bi%3Adb47725d645f676bb23b2df6de97e39f435ab84078e36fcce4b86979036aa792%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%22'+publicIp+'%22%3A31148%2C%22time%22%3A1483005349%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1483005349.437956%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%7D',
    'ig_pr': '1',
    'ig_vw': '1367',
    'csrftoken': '3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f',
    'ds_user_id': myid,
}
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com', 
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
    'accept-language': 'uk,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6', 
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrftoken': '3jmx9MnnQ1NlU46TdGQqzpNwyBdNhi0f', 
    'x-instagram-ajax': '1', 
    'accept': '*/*', 
    'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/1foobar/following/', 
    'authority': 'www.instagram.com', 
    'content-length': '0', 
    'dnt': '1'
}
r = requests.post('https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/' + uid + '/unfollow/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data={})
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the server return when it fails? Status 200 does not mean much in this case, try looking at r.text.

Also, did you try the curl before the other library? You didn't change the CSRF token between the two. When implemented correctly, this will be invalidated after 1 try.